# Is there a freelancers' website only for Windows Server troubleshooting jobs?

Tags: freelance-websites, client-support, information-technology

I am an Infrastructure engineer on the Windows Platform and I live in India. Is there a website dedicated for remote freelance troubleshooting and remote administrator jobs for the Windows Server Platform?

Websites like Elance.com, Odesk.com and some others are very generic and do not target a specific client-group.

Comment: What have you searched for on Google? What have other Freelancers in your circle told you as working and not working? What about StackOverflow Careers?

Comment: @CanadianLuke Searching `Windows admin jobs to work remotely` gets you some relevant jobs but all on generic sites. I don't have other similar freelancers in my social circle. And `StackOverflow Careers` are all for developers.

Comment: SO Careers is for anything computer related, although they lean towards programmers. I see jobs posted for Linux or Windows Server Admins, as well as the regular programming jobs. Just so you know. Do you want an invite there?

Comment: @CanadianLuke I couldn't find it [SO careers](http://careers.stackoverflow.com/jobs?searchTerm=microsoft+windows+cluster&allowsremote=true). Check the link. All developers' jobs.

Comment: If you remove the 'work remotely', there are HUNDREDS of Admin jobs.

Comment: @CanadianLuke But those would require me to be in that country; Canada, England etc. I live in India. I have to `work remotely`.

Comment: Alright, add all that information to your question then. That way, others can see your restriction, and that you have tried some things already

Answer (score 4):

I think the role you're trying to fit, because it is moreso task oriented and not product (deliverable) oriented, is not a good fit for the websites you're describing in the comments.  Aside from that -- consider something else.

I run a business.  Now, please keep reading - but this is not a personal slight to you, okay?  It'd be a rare, rare, RARE occasion when I allow someone who I've never seen, who lives in another country, who I am likely to never meet face-to-face, to connect to my business Windows (or other) infrastructure machines from wherever I've been ***told*** such a person is located, and then assume administrative tasks!!!  That person might be the best administrator in the world but if something's screwed up and I incur a loss, I can't say, "Oh, not my fault.  Blame Lars/Abdul/Kiswele/Hanna in Senegal/Budapest/Mumbai/Caracas"!!!  I can't establish a chain-of-control, and would thus be held liable for any damages.  I can't sue and recover those damages from someone halfway around the globe -- at least not easily.

If such a person were attached to a larger business, it might work out better - but I'm still not going to pass on much in the way of administration tasks.  It leaves me far too vulnerable.

Comment: I am an ex-Microsoft employee. People would pay >$750\hr to get their issues fixed. We would troubleshoot servers worldwide from India. I could do the same work at a fraction of that rate. The website would maintain a profile of the freelancer and if the ex-customer feedback is in the public domain, I don't see a problem. I am not looking for a full-time job more like a pay-per-task solution.

Comment: I'm curious to know if this is microsoft specific. My husband does exactly this - remote admin from the other side of the world - for Linux servers and he certainly has no problem finding clients.

Comment: Ayan, it will take time to build your own stable of paying clients that give business to you for the sake of what YOU can do (and not who you work for).  The freelancer sites are low hanging fruit, and if you can find any work, there's not much to help build your reputation (your "brand").  If I were you, I'd consider some alternative ways to market yourself -- identifying with others as a **business entity** may get you further than trying to communicate that you're just Joe Anybody with a laptop somewhere.

Comment: Yes, but Microsoft would take liability for any mess up you made, appoint the next guy to fix it and the client will be happy. If you go missing for weeks, or busy with other work, the client, like codenoire would be fuming, and loosing money. Also, codeniore could sue you personally for negligence, resulting in civil liability, outside/or including of your Limited Liability company. I agree with codeniore, I would not hire somebody from outside my city to fix anything at my company or home, unless the company is big enough to guarantee to fix issues, which a 1 man band cant guarantee :(

Comment: @StaceyAnne This is Microdoft-specific. I've been working on their products all my life. First a sys admin and now an Infrastructure engineer.

Comment: @WillyWonka That's why the customer-feedback  should be in the public domain.